# ColdFusion API and Websockets

Tags: websocket, coldfusion

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a CF2021 Server which uses a Node.js websocket server and CF pages (via javascript) as a client. Messages from user to user work as expected, so no issue there.

This CF Server also has a custom API built using CFML that handles and routes inbound SMS messages. My question is; what would be the best way to send the SMS message (by now its json) to the Node.js websocket to it can send it to the user(s).

I tried using the same javascript that the browser client uses, but it appears that the CFML API script is "browser-less", so that doesn't work, or should it?

I thought something like Apache Groovy may be the solution, but I am having difficulties with any websocket example I have found.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Flow matters.

If you want to handle an incoming message by delivering it to all currently logged in users who are subscribed to messages of the current sort: set up your message handler to deliver using lucee/adobe-coldfusion websockets. Be forewarned, Lucee takes some setup time, but once running, it is a great solution.

If you don't need immediate delivery, or you need a super simple solution: I actually have had some success with "Long Polling" you just have to remember to use "flush" early in the request, before any pause/sleep, then loop your message lookup requests for new data, with a 1-5 second delay between each loop. Once new data is found, I like to return the request to the client, close that polling request and start a new polling request using the client side. I typically won't poll for more than 60 seconds. Even if the returned json object is empty.